# Simple markov chain: passing cards around a circle

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider a circle of 5 people in which one person initially has $2$ cards in his hand. He passes each card to either the person on his left or his right (for each card, 50% chance left, 50% chance right).

At each step, if someone holds a card, he passes it to the right or the left with equal probability. What is the expected number of steps to have someone holding both cards in his hands (as in the beginning configuration).

---

Seems like a pretty simple probability problem. At any point in time, there are there possible states:

A: both cards held by the same person

B: the two cards held by two different people who are not adjacent

C: the two cards held by adjacent people

We can easily write the probabilities for transitioning from one state to another. I could write it as a matrix, but I don't know how to in latex so I'll just write it like this:

$A\to A: 1/2$

$A\to B: 1/2$

$A\to C: 0$

$B\to A: 1/4$

$B\to B: 1/2$

$B\to C: 1/4$

$C\to A: 0$

$C\to B: 1/4$

$C\to C: 3/4$

Define $a$ as the expected number of steps to reach state $A$ beginning at state $A$, $b$  the expected number of steps to reach state $A$ beginning at state $B$, $c$ the expected number of steps to reach state $A$ beginning at state $C$.

We thus have a simple system of equations:

$a=(1/2) \cdot 1+(1/2)\cdot (b+1)$

$b=(1/4)\cdot (1)+(1/2)\cdot (b+1)+(1/4)\cdot (c+1)$

$c=(1/4)\cdot (b+1)+(3/4)\cdot (c+1)$

which gives $(a,b,c)=(5,8,12)$.

Apparently this does not give the right answer, but I don't see the error.

**Edit:** even after fixing the mistake pointed in the answer below, the answer is still wrong.

Comment: If I understand well how the game is played, some cases are missing in your modelisation. For instance, after two steps, one of my cards could be back in my hand but the other one in the hand another, non-adjacent, player.

Comment: that would be state B

Comment: Oh, ok I understood "adjacent" as "adjacent to the first player". Sorry.

Comment: what makes you think that the answer is wrong?

Comment: Your (edited) answer looks correct to me.  Why do you say it's wrong?  Do you know what the answer is supposed to be?

Comment: We give $a=(1/2)⋅1+(1/2)⋅(b+1)$, but shouldn't it be $a=(1/2)⋅1+(1/4)⋅(b+1)$, since the probability of reaching A from B is $1/4$ ?

Comment: according to my friend, its wrong. maybe he told me the problem incorrectly... as a far as i can see the method is solid. my friend said he doesn't understand the method used to write the equations in the system, because it's not clear how they follow from the definition of expected value. i told him it's just the law of total expecation

Comment: @Evargalo: no, its the probability of reaching B from A which matters

Comment: Maybe you should challenge your friend to show you how he got what he thinks is the right answer.

Comment: I solved this a different way—by introducing a ”start” state and then using well-known results for absorbing Markov chains—and got the same expected times to absorption as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] Actually you have the right transition probabilities but B is non-adjacent, C adjacent.

There is a problem with your equations below, as you should not have the $(a+1)$ terms (if you move to $A$ you have finished). So it should be

$a=\frac12\times 1+\frac12(b+1)$

and

$b=\frac14\times 1+\frac12(b+1)+\frac14(c+1)$.

Comment: sorry i just mixed up the definitions  B and C in the first paragraph can you check again if everything is correct now.

Comment: ok edited, but the answer is still wrong

Comment: What makes you think the answer is still wrong? I just wrote a quick program to simulate it, and got average times from the three states of $5.05$, $8.04$, $11.96$ (doing $100000$ runs for each). So I'm pretty sure $(5,8,12)$ is correct.